# Вылетает ошибка: InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

В моём приложении после регистрации пользователя, при входе на страницу пользователя вылетает ошибка:

> InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property
>   'replace' of undefined

В частности из-за `jwt-decode`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
class Profile extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    errors: {},
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  const token = localStorage.usertoken
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
  this.setState({
    name: decoded.name,
    email: decoded.email
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы дал небольшую рекомендацию по поводу хранилища. Если в метод `getItem()` интерфейса `Storage` передать ключ в качестве параметра, то метод вернет значение, лежащее в хранилище по указанному ключу. Возвращаемым значением является строка `DOMString`, содержащая значение для соответствующего ключа.  Если ключ не существует, то будет возвращено значение `null`.

```
// Ваш способ получения значения из хранилища
const oldTokenGetter = localStorage.usertoken;
// Рекомендуемый способ получения значения из хранилища
const newTokenGetter = localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
```

Конечно, это не ошибка, ведь в `Storage` значения помещенных ключей хранятся как проперти объекта и Вы получите свое значение по имени.

Советы и рекомендации оставим и перейдем к полученной ошибке:

> InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Кроется в пакете `jwt-decode`. Можно найти в гите следующее ишшуе: [JWT InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/issues/65) Там в комментариях имеется подсказка, как избежать такой ошибки. В вашем случае нужно поступить так (добавить проверку, что значение имеется):

```
componentDidMount() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken');

  if (token) {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    this.setState({
      name: decoded.name,
      email: decoded.email,
    });
  }
}
```

Увы, но судя по исходникам такая проблема имеется и кроется в следующем модуле либы: [base64_url_decode.js](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/master/lib/base64_url_decode.js), который вызывается из основного модуля [(index.js)](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/master/lib/index.js)

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваша рекомендация по поводу хранилища удалась!))